In IIS + ASP.NET + Windows Debugger, Can't download symbol from the microsoft symbol server
I have built a REST API server that runs WinDbg.exe with IIS + ASP.NET.

IIS version:  10.0.17763.1
OS version : Window Server 2019
ASP.NET : .NET Framework 4.7.2

In the test environment that is not deployed with IIS, it works fine without any problems.
But when deploying to an production server using IIS, there is a problem where symbols are not downloaded from the Microsoft symbol server.
Since symbols are downloaded well when running WinDbg.exe directly on the production server, it it not considered a firewall problem.
[production server]
Use WinDbg.exe directly - It can download symbols from the Microsoft Symbol Server.
Use REST API + WinDbg.exe from IIS + APS.NET - It can't download symbols.
I wonder if there are any additional setting that need to be made for IIS to download symbols.
If additional settings are required, I would appreciate it if you could provide detailed instructions on what to set.
Thanks.


Keep in mind there are huge differences between the two, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 So, your code won't run the same way. 2) A web app is very vulnerable to attacks, so running a debugger behind it can be very risky. You'd better think twice if that's really what you want.


Please provide specific steps to reproduce the problem, such as code examples. Is there any error message or log for It can't download symbols?

I can only check this message.
Module name            Error
ntkrnlmp               No error - symbol load deferred
You can troubleshoot most symbol related issues by turning on symbol loading diagnostics (!sym noisy) and repeating the command that caused symbols to be loaded.
You should also verify that your symbol search path (.sympath) is correct.
But, if I run debugger without the IIS web, it can download successfully. Even when I run the same code as a console app instead if web app, it works well... I don't know  what the problem is.

I don't quite understand using the REST API and APS.NET with WinDbg.exe to download symbols. WinDBG.exe is just an analytic tool. And check the permissions associated with it.

I found the solution. It had auth problems. Thanks for your help.
